# filter out curly brace from HTTP payload with python

Tags: python, xml

I'm trying to convert some http payload to valid XML with a small python script, but I cannot seem to filter out the curly braces that surround the payload. I'm using the following python code:

```
print "Python Script: Convert To XML"

class Converter:
   def __init__(self,payload):
     self.xml=""
     self.xmlStart='<?xml version="1.0" ?><order>'
     self.xmlStop='</order>'
     self.payload=payload

   def convert2XML(self): 
     elements=self.payload.split(',')
     for item in elements:
       label,value = item.split('=')
       print "Label: %s, Value: %s" % (label,value)
       self.xml+="<"+label+">"+value+"</"+label+">"
     return self.xmlStart+self.xml+self.xmlStop

print "MESSAGE: ",message
print "PAYLOAD: ",payload
xml=Converter(payload)
result=xml.convert2XML()
```

The input payload is the following `{itemA=value, itemB=value, itemC=value}`
which results in te following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<order>
  <{itemA>value</{itemA>
  <itemB>value</itemB>
  <itemC>value}</itemC>
</order>
```

I've tried filtering out the braces with statements like

```
text.replace('{', '')
text.replace('}', '')
```

Not sure if this has been asked before, as my google skills did not help me today.

Answer (score 0):

Strings in Python are immutable.  Instead, try to build a new string, something like:

```
newPayload1 = oldPayload.replace("}", "")
newPayload2 = newPayload1.replace("{", "")
```

Let us know if this is what you tried?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I've ended up with the following piece of code, as I discovered that the spaces behind the comma were also a break point:

    `#print "MESSAGE: ",message
    print "PAYLOAD: ",payload
    newPayload1=payload.replace("{", "")
    newPayload2=newPayload1.replace("}", "")
    newPayload3=newPayload2.replace(" ", "")
    xml=Converter(newPayload3)
    result=xml.convert2XML()`

edit: Not sure how I can display that snippet properly

Answer (score 0):

You could strip the first and last character of the payload and split at the commas.
When working with XML, you should use the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library that cares about all the tag stuff and many things more:

```
from lxml import etree

def convert2XML(payload):
    root = etree.Element("order")

    for key, value in payload:
        sub = etree.SubElement(root, key)  # adds the sub elements to root element
        sub.text = value

    return etree.tostring(root, xml_declaration=True, encoding="utf-8")

payload = "{itemA=value, itemB=value, itemC=value}"
pay = [item.split('=') for item in payload[1:-1].split(', ')]
print(pay)  # >> pairs of item, value
xml = convert2XML(pay)
print(xml)
```

Returns a valid xml string:

```
b"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>\n<order><itemA>value</itemA><itemB>value</itemB><itemC>value</itemC></order>"
```

Comment: This seems as a better overall end solution. I'v not been able to test it though, as the runtime cannot seem to access the LXML module.....